Obtener una descripción dependiendo de donde se haga click sobre una imagen
soy nuevo en esto (realmente nuevo) estoy aprendiendo a programar python
quiero poder subir una imagen (ejemplo una persona)  y que dependiendo donde haga click se encierre en un circulo, ejemplo subo la imagen y hago click en la Cabeza y las manos, y despues poder generar un excel con esas descripciones....(sera mas eleaborado pero inicialmente quiero hacer eso)
me podrán orientar sobre que funciones usar, o cuales me podran ayudar o sobre que tema puedo leer que me ayude a poder hacer esa App?
muchas gracias ! quedo a tento
saludos

Buneas, me agrada tu publicación y tu idea, pero el sitio como tal no permite este tipo de preguntas. Lo que tienes que hacer es un [mre], con el cual nosotros poder ver que estás intentando, y que código has usado. Has dicho que quieren identificar partes de una imagen y que muestre una descripcion, comienza por hacer la parte de la imagen al menos.
